# SQS messages to trigger same lambda function instances one to one

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a requirement where at a single point of time each SQS messages in the same SQS queue should trigger separate lambda instances

For Example the SQS queue has n number of messages at a given time then expectation is , it should trigger n instance of lambdas

```
Message_1 --> Lambda_function_A_instance_1
Message_2 --> Lambda_function_A_instance_2
Message_n --> Lambda_function_A_instance_n
```

Use case :
Need to keep separate instance of lambda functions for each messages in order to process data files which are > 10G..
So each message will invoke new lamnda instance of the same function

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Is there some problem you are wanting to workaround?

Answer (score 2):

To configure Lambda to read only one message from SQS at a time, you need to set the `BatchSize` parameter to `1` when creating the SQS event source mapping. This will ensure that only one message is read from the queue at a time.

Additionally, you can set the `VisibilityTimeout` parameter to a value that is greater than the Lambda function's timeout value to ensure that the message is not processed multiple times.

Comment: Typical [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig) from AWS documentation is to set the source queue's visibility timeout to at least six times the timeout that you configure on your function.

Comment: This allows sequence , I'm expecting parallel invocation of lambda instances

Comment: You need to set the concurrency in Lambda to allow multiple lambda to be invoked at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same requirement in a project I am working on, what we did was setting the BatchSize parameter to 1 as suggested by Chaitanya and the AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-params

AWS documentation also provides good examples on how to describe it with SAM (which is what we use in our project):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-sqs.html